# Login website with yammer credentials?

Tags: javascript, yammer

Can I log-in to my website (not any application) with the yammer credentials?
Has anyone used Yammer to log-in to their websites?

Comment: Check Yammer API Docs https://developer.yammer.com/docs if you want to find out.

Comment: I know that we can use Yammer credentials to authenticate an app user.But can I authenticate a website user ? If yes,please throw some light into it.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in multiple ways. There is the [Sign-In with Yammer Button](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/authentication) and the [server-side flow](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2). My preference is for the latter option since you can modify or reuse many client side OAuth libraries. With the social authentication providers in ASP.NET MVC I was able to implement a few methods and it completely plugged in with Yammer and the ASP.NET membership system.